# Does the string contain ASCII zenkaku?

Tags: java, regex, character-encoding, character, match

I want to check if the string (received from a password type field) includes Japanese Zenkaku characters or not, but I have no idea how to check it using Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) and, thanks to [the work of this guy](https://gist.github.com/terrancesnyder/1345094), you have all the RegEx you need already prepared.

Here are the *zenkaku* related:

```
Regex for matching full-width Katakana (zenkaku 全角)
([ァ-ン])

Regex for matching full-width Numbers (zenkaku 全角)
([０-９])

Regex for matching full-width Letters (zenkaku 全角)
([Ａ-ｚ])

Regex for matching full-width (zenkaku) Katakana codespace characters (includes 
non phonetic characters)
([ァ-ヶ])
```

---

**EDIT**: Adding [@ChrisB comment](https://gist.github.com/terrancesnyder/1345094#comment-1265689) to the question:

> Actually the regexes for hiragana and katakana are too restrictive.
>
> e.g. the katakana regex would not match words containing the `長音符`, 
> such
>   as `ユーザー` and `コンピューター`.
>
> Here are some more comprehensive regexes for hiragana and katakana:
>
> - Hiragana = `[ぁ-ゔゞ゛゜ー]`  // 0x3041-0x3094, 0x309E, 0x309B, 0x309C, 0x30FC
> - Katakana = `[ァ-・ヽヾ゛゜ー]`  // 0x30A1-0x30FB, 0x30FD, &#x30FE, 0x309B, 0x309C, 0x30FC
> - Hiragana or katakana = `[ぁ-ゔゞァ-・ヽヾ゛゜ー]`  //0x3041-0x3094, 0x309E, 0x30A1-0x30FB, 0x30FD, &#x30FE, 0x309B, 0x309C, 0x30FC

Comment: Actually some of the regexes in the linked gist are not quite correct. See my comment for better ones: https://gist.github.com/terrancesnyder/1345094#comment-1265689

Comment: Great, feel free to edit my answer with your comment and link @ChrisB

Comment: @ChrisB I've added your comment to the answer. *On trust* :D

Comment: Totally OT but... wow! http://www.dramafever.com/news/new-font-incorporates-english-pronunciation-guide-into-japanese-katakana-characters-/